# GMP functions failing — C (under Carbon), XCode 3.2.5, MacOS 10.6.8

Tags: c, xcode, gmp

I am writing a program in C, under XCode 3.2.5, under Snow Leopard (10.6.8).

I have compiled, made etc. GMP a number of times, and I think (or hope!) I have that aspect under control.  I am installing it in a sub-directory under /Developer/usr, and I have added search paths (and the -lgmp entry) as per the advice I have found on the www.  (I have put in usr/local entries before my install path, just in case that helps somehow.)

I got an error as follows:  `“ld: warning: in /Developer/usr/gmp-5.1.2_core2-apple-darwin10.8.0/lib/libgmp.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)”.`

When I compile etc. for the platform that the compiler chooses (being core2-apple-darwin10.8.0) — either explicitly or by letting it choose — I get the above message.

When I compile etc., specifying the “build” and “host” as i386 (as per the above error message), I get no build errors.  However…

The functions appear to be doing nothing.  For instance, the following line

```
blCheckSetStr = mpz_init_set_str (zNumber, "85", 10);
```

appears to set zNumber to 1.  However, when I refer to it later, I get the error message `“EXC_BAD_ACCESS”`.

For what I assume to be the same reason, I have found several commands that do not work, and have substituted other commands.

I would really appreciate any help, please.  Thank you in advance.

! !  p.s.  I should have mentioned:  in my program (in C), I have been unable to use functions; I worked around this by just including everything in `main`.  I am guessing that this is probably related to why the GMP functions are not working.  (Sorry; I forgot about it because it was no longer an issue for me.)

Comment: Did you read the gmp installation doc? In particular where it mentions setting ABI=32?

Comment: I noticed several mentions of it.  It looked to me as though, as long as my system was capable of 64-bit processing, it would not matter.  I take it that you are telling me that I should probably set ABI=32.

Comment: I meant to say “thank you”.  I added (only) “--disable-shared” and “ABI=32” — still “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Comment: Ditto for “./configure --prefix=/Developer/usr/gmp-5.1.2_disableShared_ABI\=32 --build=i386 --host=i386 --disable-shared ABI=32”.

Comment: I wanted to answer my own question, but I can not see how to do that.  It is somewhat embarrassing, but I shall include all the gory details anyway, in case it helps anyone else.

Comment: I wanted to answer my own question, but I can not see how to do that.  It is somewhat embarrassing, but I shall include all the gory details anyway, in case it helps anyone else.

I worked out why I could not use functions; I was trying to pass variables rather than values, and apparently you have to use `&` instead of `*` in the call.  (This is in spite of me being very careful to copy _exactly_ how it was in the manual.)

I do need to use `--disable-shared`; otherwise, it creates a dynamic library that does not work.

Comment: As for the GMP issue of the functions doing nothing:  I was not initialising the variables.  Yes, I did read that you have to initialise variables as well as creating them.  I was very careful to observe this instruction, but somehow it all failed to work anyway.  

###  In my defence, I note that `inits` does not work; you have to use `init`.

I could not say exactly where it went wrong, though.  They say that all’s well that ends well.  <Sigh>.

Comment: Maybe you should use a C++ wrapper to GMP, it makes it as easy to use as int or long.